# 12.10, run from USB to check compatibility

Tags: 12.10

thinking of switching from Win8 to Ubuntu 12.1. Could you go with the "Run from USB stick" to verify compatibility with hardware or will that run in some kind of virtual environment?

//Daniel

Comment: Also check Linux-compatibility of devices on board by https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe (after booting in Live mode from USB stick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will run on your Hardware except the HDD, but this shouldnt be a Problem. Ther is no virtual environment.

You can try Ubuntu from USB Stick to gain an insight, if your Hardware would make trouble or not, but is is NOT a guarantee, that a real installation will not make some troubles.

For the beginning, you can try to install a dualboot to save your Windows installation.

Needless to say, that you should make a backup bevor you do anything!